# Create table if not exists Java SQL syntax error

Tags: java, sql, create-table

it seems like i cant figure out the error of the second statement (stmt). The first one (pst) executes successfully. The second one throws a message saying "Syntax error...near '78(this is the value i texted in every jTextField) (ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, IDClean INTEGER NOT_NULL FORE' at line 1.

ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ, ΕΣΟΔΑ are greek words

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
try {
        Connection conn = dbConnector2();
        String sql = "insert into cleaning (ADDRESS, DIMOS, TK, ONOMA, PHONENUM) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
        pst.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
        pst.setString(5,jTextField5.getText());

        pst.execute();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Επιτυχής Αποθήκευση");

             String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + jTextField1.getText() 
            + "(ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            + " IDClean INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY(IDClean) REFERENCE 
 cleaning(IDClean),"
            + "  ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ           DATE,"
            + "  ΕΣΟΔΑ           DOUBLE)";

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(sqlCreate);

        dispose();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Please reference the DBMS you are using. It might help on validating vendor specific syntaxes.

Comment: I believe it's `mysql`. Unfortunately, I cannot help with that for you. However, you can try if the sql command works. E.g. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_table (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    IDClean INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY(IDClean) REFERENCE cleaning(IDClean),
    ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ           DATE,
    ΕΣΟΔΑ           DOUBLE
)`.

Then you can try to run in in a background thread, otherwise the GUI becomes unresponsive.

Comment: I'm Using InnoDB engine on MySql Workbench

Comment: Have you tried running only parts of the `create table` statement? I would suggest doing that to weed out any false error line references. Also, since you are using MySql Workbench, you could try running a hard-coded variant of the `create table` directly there.

Comment: Tried to create it through MySQL Workbench, thats the result:

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY(IDClean) 
REFERENCE cleaning(IDClean), ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ DATE, Ε' at line 3
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`. tmp_table 
( ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 IDClean INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY(IDClean) 
REFERENCE cleaning(IDClean), ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ DATE, ΕΣΟΔΑ DOUBLE )

Comment: It might be because of the use of "special" characters. You could try surround the greek letter column names with back ticks, e.g. `\`ΕΣΟΔΑ\``. That might help.

Comment: I did that, but sql is fine with that, even without the back ticks. Error still exists..
Line 3 is:  IDClean INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY(IDClean)

Comment: try running this query instead, and see if works: 
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_table ( ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, IDClean INTEGER NOT NULL, ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ DATE, ΕΣΟΔΑ DOUBLE, FOREIGN KEY(IDClean) REFERENCES cleaning(IDClean));` I just ran that in mysql via terminal against the table `cleaning(IDclean INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)`, and it worked just fine.

Comment: So i tried nearly everything and it seems like the error occures due to "+jTextField.getText()" . Is there a way to create a table by fetching the name from a text field?